# Chrome Extension - Find all open tabs and execute script on all

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, tabs, manifest

Trying to modify my code for when the extension button is clicked, it will execute on all open tabs instead of only the active one.

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-2.1.0.min.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "change.js"});
  });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,    
  "name": "GSHOP",
  "version": "2",
  "description": "I do Stuff",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "background.js"]
   },
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

I believe I have the logic down I just can't figure how to do it.  I believe I need to find how many tabs are open `tabs.length?` and iterate over them, but I just cannot get it to work.

**Doesn't Work**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tabs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "jquery-2.1.0.min.js" },    function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "change.js"});
            });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query( {} ,function (tabs) { // The Query {} was missing here
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "jquery-2.1.0.min.js"});
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "change.js"});
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` callbacks take a single `tab` object for the current tab. Not a list of all tabs. Inside the `onClicked` callback you will have to run [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) and loop through the tabs in the `query` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Hope this one helps.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    executeScriptsInExistingTabs();
});

function executeScriptsInExistingTabs(){
    chrome.windows.getAll(null, function(wins) {
      for (var j = 0; j < wins.length; ++j) {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(wins[j].id, function(tabs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("chrome://") != 0) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { file: 'js/change.js' });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```